# Ввод данных в одной строке

Tags: c++

Как организовать ввод целочисленных данных в одной строке? Пример:

1 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::cin >> x >> y;

Как вводить - без разницы.
Данные могут быть разделены любыми пробельными символами.